# (dplyr) Error when using mutate(), case_when() and which()

Tags: r, date, dplyr

Need help with error/warnings in the following situation:

I have a data frame with date of observation and a vector of such dates. I want to create new columns in the data frame with next and previous observation dates. The dates vector is created as:

```
library(glue)

dates = c("201902",
          "201906",
          "201911",
          "202002")

dates = glue("{dates}01")

dates = dates%>%
        as.Date(format = "%Y%m%d")%>%
        sort()
```

Then my data frame has this column made of `dates` elements, called `Date`. I want it to create columns with the next and previous dates, or keep the same if it is the start/end. I'm using:

```
library(dplyr)

my_df = my_df%>%
mutate(First_date = (Date == dates[1]),
       Last_date = (Date == dates[length(dates)]),
       Prev_date = case_when(First_date ~ Date,
                                   TRUE ~ dates[which(dates == Date)-1]),
       Next_date = case_when(Last_date ~ Date,
                                  TRUE ~ dates[which(dates == Date)+1])
```

EXAMPLE: If I had a dataframe with the following column:

```
>my_df$Date
[1] "2019-02-01" "2019-06-01" "2019-11-01" "2020-02-01"
```

I would like it to end up with:

```
>my_df$First_date
[1] TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
>my_df$Last_date
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE
>my_df$Prev_date
[1] "2019-02-01" "2019-02-01" "2019-06-01" "2019-11-01"
>my_df$Next_date
[1] "2019-06-01" "2019-11-01" "2020-02-01" "2020-02-01"
```

The test data frame I'm using has 6 rows, and it throws this error and warnings:

```
Error: `TRUE ~ dates[which(dates == Date) + 1]` must be length 6 or one, not 2
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In `==.default`(dates, Date) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
2: In `==.default`(dates, Date) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

I reckon this must have something to do with calling the `which()` function inside a `case_when()`, inside a `mutate()`, but I haven't managed to figure out exactly where it goes wrong.

It is my first time asking here, sorry for any mistake!

Comment: Cannot replicate this because I do not know where `RFB_dates` comes from...

Comment: Sorry @broti, that was a typo I missed. Corrected it already

Comment: I am not sure what columns your final data frame is supposed to have: Just `Date`? Or `First_date`, `Last_date`, `Prev_date` and `Next_date`?

Comment: @broti, I wanted for it to end up with all the four new columns, plus the original one. `mutate()` should just do that, right?

Comment: So the four columns will each have only one value? The best thing would be for you to provide the desired output as a data frame

Comment: @broti one value per row, yes. To clarify: I want to make some conditional analysis further down the road and for each observation I would like for it to be explicit whether it is an initial (first date), last (last date) and what are the next and previous dates

Comment: I will do just that! Hang in there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this should do. First, your df:

```
dates = c("201902",
          "201906",
          "201911",
          "202002")

dates = glue("{dates}01")

dates = dates%>%
        as.Date(format = "%Y%m%d")%>%
        sort()

my_df <- data.frame(Date = dates)
```

Then, using the `shift` function:

```
my_df <- my_df %>%
  mutate(First_date = ifelse(Date == dates[1], TRUE, FALSE),
         Last_date = ifelse(Date == dates[length(dates)], TRUE, FALSE),
         Prev_date = shift(dates, n = 1, fill = dates[1]),
         Next_date = shift(dates, n = -1, fill = dates[length(dates)]))
```

```
> my_df
        Date First_date Last_date  Prev_date  Next_date
1 2019-02-01       TRUE     FALSE 2019-02-01 2019-06-01
2 2019-06-01      FALSE     FALSE 2019-02-01 2019-11-01
3 2019-11-01      FALSE     FALSE 2019-06-01 2020-02-01
4 2020-02-01      FALSE      TRUE 2019-11-01 2020-02-01
```

Comment: It sounds to me like your trying to apply the code to a different data frame with 6 rows - try to restart with the code I have posted.

Comment: I noticed this works for exactly a dataframe with the 4 date observations, but not for mutating a bigger dataframe with multiple repetitions of each date. I am trying to use your method to adapt a merge. If it works, it'll be very helpful!

Comment: Try to just make the `dates` vector longer, e.g. by `dates_new <- rep(dates, 2)`, and build the df based on that with `data.frame(Date = dates)`. Code will still work!

Comment: This has helped! I shall use a `join` function to bring this data frame info to the one I'm working with.

Comment: my main dataframe has over 9 million lines. I wanted to mutate it straightforwardly, but creating this auxiliary my_df (as you did) and then joining should do the trick.

Comment: No worries. Advice for asking questions: From the start, provide a (small) data frame from which you can extrapolate to your real data. Makes helping faster.

Comment: yes, I totally forgot to provide a sample, my bad. Thanks for the advice!